# Saving edits to database made in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

### How can I adapt my code to any changes that are made remain persistent?

As I understand I need to update the datatable which in turn will update the database. So I have tried to use the update command like below on a button click event.

```
adb.Update(dt);
```

However this doesn't seem to work, so I am obviously missing something, but I'm not sure what?.

### Code

```
String ConnStr = "Data Source=database.com\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=Data; User ID=mobile; Password=password";
String SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status  FROM dbo.joblist WHERE username = @username and status = @status";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);

try
{
    con.Open();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auditorCmb.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = statusCmb.Text;

SqlDataAdapter adb = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{

    try
    {
        adb.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know SqlDataAdapter does not generate insert, update or delete commands on its own.

You have to either set them manually - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx.

Or generate them with [SqlCommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public static DataSet SelectSqlRows(string connectionString,
>     string queryString, string tableName)
> {
>     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>     {
>         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
>         adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
>         SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
>
>         connection.Open();
>
>         DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
>         adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);
>
>         //code to modify data in DataSet here
>
>         builder.GetUpdateCommand();
>
>         //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
>         adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);
>
>         return dataSet;
>     }
> }
> ```